# jQuery hover not working in Safari or Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, hover

I'm implementing a jQuery hover effect on some list items. It works perfectly in all browsers except Safari and Google Chrome (Mac and PC). For some reason the hover effect doesn't work on these two to browsers.

Here's the code (it also uses the **color_library.js** plugin):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var originalBG = $("#menu li#Q_01","#menu li#Q_03","#menu li#Q_05","#menu li#Q_07","#menu li#Q_09","#menu li#Q_11","#menu li#Q_11").css("background-color");    
  var originalBG1 = $("#menu li").css("color");
  var originalBG2 = $("#menu li#Q_02","#menu li#Q_04","#menu li#Q_06","#menu li#Q_08","#menu li#Q_10","#menu li#Q_12").css("background-color");

  var fadeColor = "#009FDD"; 
  var fadeColor1 = "#FFF";
  var fadeColor2 = "#623A10"; 

  $("#menu li#Q_01").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor2,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },
    function () {
      $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
  }
  );

$("#menu li#Q_03").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor2,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
  }
  );

$("#menu li#Q_05").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor2,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
  }
  );

$("#menu li#Q_07").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor2,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
  }
  );

$("#menu li#Q_09").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor2,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
  }
  );

$("#menu li#Q_11").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor2,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
  }
  );

$("#menu li#Q_13").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor2,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },
  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
  }
  );



$("#menu li#Q_02").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },

  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
    }
   );

$("#menu li#Q_04").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },

  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
    }
   );

$("#menu li#Q_06").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },

  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
    }
   );

$("#menu li#Q_08").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },

  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
    }
   );

$("#menu li#Q_10").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },

  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
    }
   );

$("#menu li#Q_12").hover( function () {
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor,color:fadeColor1}, 380 )
    },

  function () {
    $(this).animate( {color:"#666",backgroundColor:"#fff"}, 380 )
    }
   );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put an `A` tag inside your `LI`s. Style and animate the links, not the `LI`s.

Comment: Thats a little painful as the style is being applied to the list item. I had a quick try at adding a link with a class but safari mac still gave unexpected results (intermittent)

Is there no easier way?

Comment: Changing the CSS to style A vs LI should be trivial, not painful.

Comment: Changing the style to an A isn't painful. But making that A look like the the list container is (time wise). I have gone with .addClass as the .hover just seems to be not so great with safari and chrome.

Thanks for your input though.